# Quotient space given an equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, quotient-set

Given $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its usual topology, we define the following equivalence relations and I'm asked for the quotient spaces:

a)$(x_1,y_1)R(x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2$

I understand that the equivalence classes are circles with center $(0,0)$, and that the quotient space here is $[0,+\infty)$ with the induced topology. To prove this I've followed the usual strategy of finding an identification.

b)$(x_1,y_1)R(x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1^2+y_1=x_2^2+y_2$

Here I don't know how to start because I can't imagine the equivalence classes. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: (a) is correct.  As for (b) consider trying to think of the equivalence class of a specific $(x_1,y_1)$.  Rather than writing $x_1^2+y_1$, let us just call that $b$.  The set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that they are related to $(x_1,y_1)$ will be those pairs for which $b = x^2+y$ or rather those pairs for which $y=-(x^2)+b$.  In other words, all those points on that parabola.  Now, consider a different equivalence class who has a different value of $b$ and so on...

Comment: Then the quotient space should be $\mathbb{R}$ right?